# Resolving all used classes from source

Tags: c#, class, oop, reflection

In Java there are the import statements at the beginning of a source file.
In most cases the full class path of each class is used (e.g. "import java.io.IOException;") in some cases a * to import the whole package.
If the full class path is used it is quite simple to tell which classes are used in this file:

All imported ones and if a class is used and not imported it is in the same package.

In C# only namespaces are imported (e.g. "using System.IO;"). It is quite hard to tell which classes are actually used.

So here is my problem: There is a quite big open source C# project. It would be an overkill to use the whole assamblie or compile the source in my project.
I just want to use one or two classes. These classes need other classes from the open source project and so on and so on,
but in the end its still just a relatively small portion of the whole project.

Is there a tool that tells me exactly which classes are used by a class? Maybe even recursive?
I could then just copy these source files in my project.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 there is a context menu action in the source window "View Call Hierarchy" to execute on a class member. In addition there is a "Hierarchy" context menu action "Hierarchy" on a class in Solution Explorer.

Comment: How about dependency walker?

Comment: BTW: `using` can also import classes as the "[using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)".

Comment: @Uwe Keim Thanks, I'll try that! I'm using MonoDevelop as IDE so I'm not that familiary with Visual Studio.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en/vs/community/) is free to download and run.

Comment: I know, I have it, I just don't like it...

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve? Not using assembly like everyone else has serious drawbacks...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I tried to make the question generic but in my usecase Bouncy Castle has a single class I want to use. I don't want to use the whole framework since it would make my app quite a bit bigger (about 4mb which is a lot in the mobile sector).

Comment: This class depends on some other classes in Bouncy Castle so I need to identify them and copy them into my project, too.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You can't separate the classes from the assembly if you're going to take a dependency on the assembly. If you're going to copy-paste code from the open-source project into your own project, you may as well do that incrementally (start by removing the reference, copy-paste one high-level class, compile to see what else needs to be copied, rinse, repeat).

Comment: As @lesscode said incremental copy-paste would be probably fastest solution if you need it once. Dont forget to add test first for functionality you need as it will let you stop earlier. Note that if you trying to get something more than some helper function you may as well search for another DI container library instead... And writing one for very specific case is not that hard either...